# Restriction of an endomorphism on a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space, of say dimension $n$. Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$ of dimension $m<n$ and let $T$ be an endomorphism; i.e. $T:V\to V$ is a linear map. I am unsure how to deal with the restriction of $T$ to $U$, $T_{|U}$.
I mean, $T_{|U}:U\to V, u\mapsto T(u)$, so $T_{|U}$ cannot be represented by a $n\times n$ matrix (but if $U$ is $T$-invariant it can be represented as a $m\times m$ matrix?)?

Specifically, I am wondering: if $T:V\to V$ is linear and has minimal polynomial $\mu_T$, and $U$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, does it hold that $\mu_T(T_{|U})=0$ and if so, why (i.e. how can I intepret this)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct provided $U$ is $T$-invariant. In this case, we can define $T\vert_U:U\rightarrow U$ and consider the endomorphism $\mu_T(T\vert_U):U\rightarrow U$. This endomorphism is indeed zero. To see this, evaluate $\mu_T(T\vert_U)$ on any vector in $U$. The answer will be the same as if you had evaluated $\mu_T(T)$ on the vector, so it is zero. However, if $U$ is not $T$-invariant, then we do not have an endomorphism of $U$, so that $\mu_T(T\vert_U)$ does not make sense.

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall try to verify this!